# Redirecting standard error out

Tags: c#, redirectstandardoutput

So what i am doing is calling java.exe and making a call to a jar file with some arguments.  If everyting is fine and the command works, then the arguments are printed out to a richtext box.

The issue I am having is when the command isn't correct.  So in once instance, say the user types in the wrong password that's passed into txtPassword.  Stanadard out is not being redirected.  If i run the exact same command in a Dos console, the message "Error: Auth fail", is being presented.  How do i redirect that error to the rich text box?  I thought redirecting stdout would do it, but apparently not.

Any help would be apprecaited.  Please see the code below.

```
  //Declare and instantiate a new process component.
                System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
                process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                process1.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe ";

                toLoad = lstBarToLoad.Items[i].Text;

               process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx512M -jar Deploy.jar" + txtPassword;
               process1.StartInfo.Arguments += toLoad;

              Console.WriteLine(process1.StartInfo.Arguments);

              process1.Start();
              process1.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => myMethod(a);
              process1.BeginOutputReadLine();

   //myMthod
     private void myMethod(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Action action = () => rchsdtOut.Text += "\r\n" + e.Data.ToString();
            rchsdtOut.BeginInvoke(action, null);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
        }
    }//end of private
```

Comment: HAve you looked at the members on `Process`? You may notice the errorDataReceived which looks like the equivalent version of OutputDataReceived... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as using

```
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

You also need to use

```
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the error output of an application is written to the Process.StandardError stream

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx

You can then read out the error and do with it as you please:

```
string error = process1.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Are you reading the error? `string error = process1.StandardError.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: So the problem with that, is now STDOUT isn't being redirected.

Comment: Are you doing:

`process1.Start();
        process1.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process1.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process1.WaitForExit();`

Comment: Yes. Here is the code I am using:         process1.Start();      
                        process1.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => myMethod(a);
                        process1.BeginOutputReadLine();

                        process1.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                        string error = process1.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                        rchsdtOut.Text = error;

Comment: comments aren't really that good for code. Let me know if you can still read it. STDError is now being redirected, but no longer my regular out.  ill post a new question since this was kinda answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RedirectStandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx) property same way as you use the RedirectStandardOutput property.